# Script ha dejado de funcionar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Llevo usando un script desde hace más de un año y de pronto, sin que haya cambiado nada en él, ha dejado de funcionar. Con él envío un mail a un listado de direcciones que tengo en una hoja de cálculo desde hace un tiempo no captura las direcciones. El script es el siguiente:

```
  var email = sheet.getRange("N1:N5").getValues();    
  // coge las direcciones de mail del listado

  var subject = sheet.getRange("J2").getValue();

  // coge los datos de la celda J2 para el asunto del correo

  var body = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 39).getValue();
  //coge los datos de la fila 39 para el cuerpo del correo      

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)
  //envía el correo
```

Me da este mensaje de error:

> Exception: Los parámetros (number[],String,String) no coinciden con la firma de método de MailApp.sendEmail.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo para que vuelva a coger todas las direcciones de mail?
Me resulta muy extraño que haya dejado de funcionar de repente sin que haya hecho ningún cambio.

Comment: Hola Laura, y bienvenida. Tienes algún mensaje de error? Tienes algún log donde comprobar si ha habido algún error en el proceso? Por los datos que das poco se puede hacer para descubrir porqué no envía el correo... Se me ocurre que quizá haya algún correo que esté mal escrito, que no tenga el formato adecuado, que haya algún caracter (como una coma al final, etc...) que quizá provoque que todo el proceso no funcione. ¿Has hecho cambios al listado de correos ultimamente? Comprueba a ver...

Comment: Hola Ferrán, no he hecho ningún cambio en la lista de correos pero si sustituyo getvalues por getvalue y le indico sólo la celda en la que está mi correo sí funciona. Me da este mensaje de error: Exception: Los parámetros (number[],String,String) no coinciden con la firma de método de MailApp.sendEmail.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben incluir un [mcve] (en tu código no está claro cómo llamas la función, cómo declaras `sheet`, entre otras cosas) . Además del código, no olvides incluir información clara sobre los datos que estás leyendo, en muchos casos es buena idea incluir una enlace a una hoja de cálculo de demostración.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al mensaje de error y la documentación de MailApp en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail el problema es que el primer argumento es `Number[]` (una colección de números) siendo que los que se espera es un String.

El problema se origina en

```
var email = sheet.getRange("N1:N5").getValues();
```

ya que `getValues()` devuelve un `Array[]` (array de arrays), y no un String.

Sin profundizar en porque funciona como funciona, primero revisar los valores de `N1:N5` quizás incluyen algo que no es una dirección de correo eletrónico.